# Yii2: how to reduce behaviors() db queries when loading controller?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am getting model object 3 times (Yii2) to load `view` controller. This makes my page to load slow. How to reduce it?

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'httpCache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\filters\HttpCache',
            'only' => ['view'],
            'lastModified' => function ($action, $params) {
                $post = $this->findModel(Yii::$app->request->get('id'));
                return strtotime($post->updated);
            },
            'etagSeed' => function ($action, $params) {
                $post = $this->findModel(Yii::$app->request->get('id'));
                return serialize([$post->updated, $post->views, $post->comments, Yii::$app->user->isGuest ? 0 : 1]);
            }
        ],
    ];
}

public function actionView($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cache model instance at controller level:

```
private $_models = [];

protected function findModel($id) {
    if (!array_key_exists($id, $this->_models)) {
        $this->_models[$id] = MyModel::findOne($id);
        if ($this->_models[$id] === null) {
            $this->notFound();
        }
    }

    return $this->_models[$id];
}
```

Only first call of `findModel()` will query DB, next calls will return already instantiated object.

Comment: Good try, thank you. Would it be better to put in cache model or it would be harder?

Comment: Caching at model level is tricky. Sometimes you need to query fresh model from DB instead of cache. And such caching may increase memory consumption if you will use many models in one request. It is easier to handle such cases at controller level, when you know that you will need always one model and you don't need to query it again.